# Sencha Touch 2 : Adding a css class dynamically to a div inside a template

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Lets assume i have a dataview with the following itemTpl

```
        itemTpl: [
        '<div class="category_entry_inner">',
        '    <div class="category_right">',
        '        <div class="category_quantity">{catQty}</div>',
        '    </div>',
        '    <div class="category_left">',
        '        <div class="category_left_content">',
        '            <div class="category_left_icon"></div>',
        '            <div class="category_left_text">{catName}</div>',
        '        </div>',
        '    </div>',
        '</div>'
    ],
```

Now what I would like to do is hook to the dataview refresh event and when fired select all divs that have a cass of category_entry_inner and add a simple class (.someclass{background:red}) to all those divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all the divs you want, you can do

```
var divs = Ext.DomQuery.select('div[class=category_entry_inner]');
```

It will return an array with all the divs and then you just need to loop through them and add a class :

```
var i,j;
for(i=0,j=divs.length;i<j;i++){
    divs[i].className += " bar";
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var listObjs = Ext.DomQuery.select("div[class='category_entry_inner']");
Ext.Array.forEach(listObjs, function(elmnt, idx) {
    Ext.get(elmnt).clearListeners();
    Ext.get(elmnt).addListener('tap', this.yourfunctionname, this, {id:elmnt.id});
}, this);
```

this is do your work definately